# Magento 2 : ERROR | Identical operator === is not used for testing the return value of strpos function

Tags: magento2.4.4, meqp2

```
foreach ($statusCollection as $statusModel)
        {
            if ($statusModel->getId() == substr($status, strpos($status, '_') + 1))
            {
                // this is it!
                $this->_frameworkRegistry = $om->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need change your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that your might have logical mistake in your code.

Function [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) returns `int|false`.

See details about this warning in official documentation:

> **Warning:** on may return Boolean **false**, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to **false**. Please read the section on **[Booleans](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)** for more information. Use **[the === operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)** for testing the return value of this function.

This means that you need to check result of `strpos` like  `!== false` before using result.